# Accessing Ext Gantt JS variable from other file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

This is my basic.js

```
Ext.ns('App');

//Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true, disableCaching : true });
//Ext.Loader.setPath('Sch', '../../../ExtScheduler2.x/js/Sch');
//Ext.Loader.setPath('Gnt', '../../js/Gnt');

Ext.require([
    'Gnt.panel.Gantt',
    'Gnt.column.PercentDone',
    'Gnt.column.StartDate',
    'Gnt.column.EndDate',
    'Sch.plugin.TreeCellEditing'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() { App.Gantt.init(); });

App.Gantt = {

    // Initialize application
    init: function (serverCfg) {
        Ext.QuickTips.init();

        var taskStore = Ext.create("Gnt.data.TaskStore", {
            model : 'Gnt.model.Task',
            proxy : {
                type : 'ajax',
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'tasks.xml',
                reader: {
                    type : 'xml',
                    // records will have a 'Task' tag
                    record: "Task",
                    root: "Tasks"
                }
            }
        });

        var dependencyStore = Ext.create("Gnt.data.DependencyStore", {
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type : 'ajax',
                url: 'dependencies.xml',
                method: 'GET',
                reader: {
                    type : 'xml',
                    root : 'Links',
                    record: 'Link' // records will have a 'Link' tag
                }
            }
        });


        var colSlider = Ext.create("Ext.slider.Single", {
            width: 120,
            value: 20, // TODO Sch.PresetManager.getPreset('weekAndDayLetter').timeColumnWidth,
            minValue: 20,
            maxValue: 140,
            increment: 10
        });

        var cellEditing = Ext.create('Sch.plugin.TreeCellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            listeners : {
                beforeedit : function() { return !Ext.getCmp('demo-readonlybutton').pressed; }
            }
        });

        var g = Ext.create('Gnt.panel.Gantt', {
            height: 350,
            width: 1000,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            leftLabelField: 'Name',
            highlightWeekends: true,
            loadMask: true,
            enableProgressBarResize: true,
            enableDependencyDragDrop: true,
            //snapToIncrement : true,
            cascadeChanges : false,
            startDate: new Date(2010, 0, 4),
            endDate: Sch.util.Date.add(new Date(2010, 0, 4), Sch.util.Date.WEEK, 10),
            viewPreset: 'weekAndDayLetter',

            eventRenderer: function (taskRecord) {
                return {
                    ctcls : taskRecord.get('Id') // Add a CSS class to the task element
                };
            },

            tooltipTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<ul class="taskTip">',
                    '<li><strong>Task:</strong>{Name}</li>',
                    '<li><strong>Start:</strong>{[Ext.Date.format(values.StartDate, "y-m-d")]}</li>',
                    '<li><strong>Duration:</strong> {Duration}d</li>',
                    '<li><strong>Progress:</strong>{PercentDone}%</li>',
                '</ul>'
            ).compile(),


            // Setup your static columns
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype : 'treecolumn',
                    header: 'Tasks',
                    sortable: true,
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    width: 200,
                    field: {
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                },
                Ext.create('Gnt.column.StartDate'),
                Ext.create('Gnt.column.EndDate'),
                Ext.create('Gnt.column.PercentDone')
            ],

            taskStore: taskStore,
            dependencyStore: dependencyStore,
            plugins: [cellEditing],

            tbar: [
                {
                    text: 'Add new task...',
                    iconCls: 'icon-add',
                    handler: function () {
                        var newTask = new taskStore.model({
                                Name: 'New task',
                                leaf : true,
                                PercentDone: 0
                            });
                        taskStore.getRootNode().appendChild(newTask);
                    }
                },
                {
                    enableToggle: true,
                    id : 'demo-readonlybutton',
                    text: 'Read only mode',
                    pressed: false,
                    handler: function () {
                        g.setReadOnly(this.pressed);
                    }
                },
                '->',
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    text: 'Column Width'
                },
                ' ',
                colSlider
            ]
        });

        colSlider.on({
            change: function (s, v) {
                g.setTimeColumnWidth(v, true);
            },
            changecomplete: function (s, v) {
                g.setTimeColumnWidth(v);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In my html file, I have included the basic.js

I want to access **var taskStore** from the basic.js , but having hard time.

I tried doing like this:

```
var test = App.Gantt.taskStore;
var test = taskStore;
```

They did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, and ugliest way, would be to assign it to window: window.taskStore = taskStore. Then any file can access this variable. A lot better would be to take a moment to consider the design of your JS application and do with Brian's advice. Who should know about the taskStore, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Using `var` means it is a private variable that cannot be accessed outside of `App.Gantt`.  Instead try setting it using `this.taskStore = ...` which sets it as a member variable of `App.Gantt` and makes it publicly accessible.

Comment: I tried defining taskStore like that, `this.taskStore` ,  getting error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: taskStore is not defined `

Comment: The easiest, and ugliest way, would be to assign it to window: window.taskStore = taskStore. Then any file can access this variable. A lot better would be to take a moment to consider the design of your JS application. Who should know about the taskStore, but I'd need to know how you intend to use it to give any advice...

Comment: FYI, when you change it to `this.taskStore` then you'd need to reference it later in that same code as `this.taskStore` also, or you'll get that undefined error.  Basically, you just need to pay attention to how you are setting your variables, and perhaps study up a bit more on how `scope` is used in JS.